# Подмена серитфиката. Теория и практика. Как узнать, кто и как подменяет серитфикат?

Tags: ssl, сертификат

Всем привет. Сегодня столкнулся с такой проблемой:
http://www.pixic.ru/i/O0m111d437p4B5j8.png

Как я могу узнать, что и на каком этапе моего интернет соединения подменяют сертификат? Я использую один из дистрибутивов linux, в режиме инкогнито отключил все расширения. Куда копать?

Comment: В данном случае никто ничего не подменяет, на самом сайте сертификат кривой

Comment: `ru.aliexpress.com использует недействительный сертификат безопасности. Сертификат действителен только для следующих имён: a248.e.akamai.net, *.akamaihd.net, *.akamaihd-staging.net, *.akamaized.net, *.akamaized-staging.net`. Сервак криво настроен, левый серт выдаёт.

Comment: Мда. Не ожидал)

Answer (score 2):

Сертификат подменяет тот самый "человек по середине". Ищите его вдоль провода от вас до Али.

*Или у вас просто часы сбиты.*

## Про комментарии, что "сайт выдает кривой сертификат"

К этому нужно относится так - сайт скомпрометирован. Не важно, сами владельцы страдают косорукостью, или кто-то решил устроить MiTM крупного масштаба, но доверять сайту в любом случае нельзя.

Comment: Не. Так сам сервак выдаёт кривой сертификат. Проблема у Али.

Comment: @kff Что значит сам сервак выдаёт ? С таким же успехом сервак могли поломать , зайти и заменить сертификат. На каком основании Вы утверждаете что это оплошность администраторов сервера али?

Answer (score 0):

> Куда копать?

В адресной строке нажмите мышкой на замочек с крестиком (левее https), откроется окно со свойствами соединения, в этом же окне можно посмотреть сертификат сервера. 
Попробуйте подключиться к серверу (https://ru.aliexpress.com/) через другое соединение, с другого компьютера, через другого провайдера. Можно попробовать яндекс.браузер в режиме Турбо. Если через разные соединения сервер выдает разные сертификаты, значит есть посредник, который пытается подменить сертификат.

Comment: Но если через разные соединения сервер тем не менее выдаёт _один и тот же_ сертификат, это не значит, что нет посредника. Это может значить, например, что посредник находится на вашем раутере или на всех ваших компьютерах.